# How to display the user image from storage/app?

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

How can I display images from the storage folder (outside public)? I stored my image files in storage/usernamee, but I'm unable to show it in the view.  How can I move the upload into "storage/images/" (under a folder name "images")?

**View**

```php
<form class="forms-sample" method="post" action="/updateprofil" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('put')
    @csrf
    <div align="center">
        <img alt="User Pic" src="{{  storage_path($membre->photo) }}" id="profile-image1"
             class="img-circle img-responsive">
        <input id="pic" class="hidden" name="pic" type="file" accept="image/*">
        <div style="color:#999;">click here to change profile image</div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="idMembre" name="membre_id" value="{{  $membre->id }}">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```php
public function updateprofil(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['cin' => 'size:8']);

    if ($request->hasFile('pic')) {
        $image = $request->file('pic');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save(storage_path("app/usernamee/" . $filename));
        $request->pic = $filename;
    }

    $membre = Membre::findOrFail($request->membre_id);
    $membre->photo = 'app/usernamee/' . $request->pic;
    $membre->update($request->all());

    return redirect('profil');
}
```

[This is my view of user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA3pa.png)

PS: The update method works for informations update but doesn't work for the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either or need to:

1) need to save the image in `storage/app/public` directory - First you need to symlink the storage path to public:

> php artisan storage:link

Then your way should work.

2) Create a route to return the image.

```
Route::get('show-image/{id}', function() {
   $membre = Membre::findOrFail($id);

   $file = storage_path($membre->photo);

   return response()->file($file);
})
```

Comment: im working on local storage, why i need to sotre in public directory ?

Comment: Use #1 is if you want to show the image publicly, otherwise use #2

Comment: I did it with #2, it works but when I edit a field for example "name" the photo disappear and it returns empty. How can I fix it please ? (I'm sorry for late)

Comment: Do you mean changing filename?

Comment: Yes and exactly when I change any filed like 'first name', 'last name', 'email' .. I mean when I change one of the fileds the image disappear

Comment: Can it be because of this line (`$membre->photo = 'app/usernamee/' . $request->pic;`) in your `updateprofil()` method?

Comment: This is where the image will be strored , If you have any idea to change it to work please tell me

Comment: If the path in database is correct and the file path is correct, it should work. Make sure you are not overriding it